# Proving existence of surjective $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ implies $A$ is at most countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Definition of "at most countable" used:** A set $A$ is at most countable iff it's finite or there exists a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$.

**Problem:** I want to prove that if there exists a surjective function from the set of natural numbers to a set $A$, then there exists a bijective function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$, with the condition that *$A$ is infinite* (Because if it´s finite, one condition is met and the problem is over).

My approach for these kind of problems used to be creating a function that just maps from the first set to the second, making permutations as necessary. But infinity is confusing me. So this is my approach so far:

Index each set with different index numbers, both natural numbers. $x$ for naturals, and $y$ for elements in $A$. So we would get $f(x_n)=y_i$, $f(x_{x+1})=y_{i+1}$ and so on. Then create another function:

$g(x_n) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    f(x_n) & \quad \text{if $\forall a<n, f(x_a)\neq y_i$}\\
    h(x_n) & \quad \text{if $\exists a<n/f(x_a)=y_i$}
  \end{array} \right.$

The problem we're trying to avoid here is having two elements in $\mathbb{N}$ so that $f$ maps them to the same $y$. Here, the so called "$h$" function: what should it do? Or is there another approach I should be using instead? (Like, Axiom of Choice and its equivalents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose $a \in A$ and let $i(a) = \min \{ m \in \mathbb{N} | f(m) = a \}$. Since $f$ is surjective, $i$ is well defined.

Let $N = \{ i(f(n)) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Note that $f \mid_N : N \to A$ is a bijection.

If $N$ is finite, then $A=f(N)$ is finite.

Otherwise, let $\phi$ be a bijective map $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to N$, then a suitable bijection is $f \circ \phi$.

Comment: I found it helpful and very elegant, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For each $y$ in $A$ you can select a single $x_n$ for which $f(x_n) = y$. Call this $g(y)$. Then $g$ is a bijection between $A$ and a subset of $\mathbb N$. Call this subset $B$. Then find a bijection $h:B \rightarrow {\mathbb N}$; you can do this by letting $h$ map the smallest element of $B$ to $1$, the second smallest element of $B$ to $2$ and so on. Then $h \circ f$ will work.

And please no axiom of choice complainers here :)